# Check if element has a certain class and belongs to a form that contains a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a validation function that will check a certain element for two things:

1. It has a certain class
2. It belongs to a form that contains a **partial** text match on the form action

For example, given the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/page1">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text1" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text2" class="red" /></li>
      <li><button id="button1" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/page2">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text3" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text4" class="blue" /></li>
      <li><button id="button2" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/page2andpage3">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text5" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text6" class="blue" /></li>
      <li><button id="button3" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'd expect to be able to create a function and get the following results:

```
isElementValid('text1', 'blue', 'page2') // false
isElementValid('button1', 'blue', 'page2') // false
isElementValid('text3', 'blue', 'page2') // false
isElementValid('text4', 'blue', 'page2') // true
isElementValid('button2', 'blue', 'page2') // true
isElementValid('button3', 'blue', 'page2') // true
```

I assume I'll be able to use [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) and [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to create something along this lines of:

```
function isElementValid(element, color, action) {
 var matchingClass = $(element).hasClass(color);
 var matchingParent = $(element).parents() //....attr('action').contains(action);
 return matchingClass && matchingParent;
}
```

But I'm unsure on the best way to check the parents for a form with the action. Is this along the right lines or is there a better approach?

Comment: This seems needlessly complex. Any input/button/select etc can just reference its form through `element.form`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if an attribute on an element contains a given value you can use the [Attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector. Then you can use the `length` property of the resulting jQuery object to determine if anything was found.

You should also note that your logic is missing the `#` selector prefix on the `element` ids you use. Try this:

```js
function isElementValid(element, color, action) {
  let $el = $('#' + element);
  let matchingClass = $el.hasClass(color);
  let matchingParent = $el.closest(`form[action*="${action}"]`).length != 0;
  return matchingClass && matchingParent;
}

console.log(isElementValid('text1', 'blue', 'page2')); // false
console.log(isElementValid('button1', 'blue', 'page2')); // false
console.log(isElementValid('text3', 'blue', 'page2')); // false
console.log(isElementValid('text4', 'blue', 'page2')); // true
console.log(isElementValid('button2', 'blue', 'page2')); // true
console.log(isElementValid('button3', 'blue', 'page2')); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/page1">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text1" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text2" class="red" /></li>
      <li><button id="button1" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
<form method="post" action="/page2">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text3" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text4" class="blue" /></li>
      <li><button id="button2" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
<form method="post" action="/page2andpage3">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text5" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text6" class="blue" /></li>
      <li><button id="button3" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery really isn't that helpful for something this trivial.

See comments in code below.

```js
function isElementValid(element, color, action) {
 // Check the element's class list and see if the supplied
 // class name is on that list. Also find the closest ancestor 
 // form and check its action to see if it contains the action parameter.
 // Return whether both tests were true or not
 return element.classList.contains(color) && element.closest("form").action.indexOf(action) > -1;
}

console.log(isElementValid(document.getElementById('text1'), 'blue', 'page2')); // false
console.log(isElementValid(document.getElementById('button1'), 'blue', 'page2')); // false
console.log(isElementValid(document.getElementById('text3'), 'blue', 'page2')); // false
console.log(isElementValid(document.getElementById('text4'), 'blue', 'page2')); // true
console.log(isElementValid(document.getElementById('button2'), 'blue', 'page2')); // true
console.log(isElementValid(document.getElementById('button3'), 'blue', 'page2')); // true
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/page1">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text1" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text2" class="red" /></li>
      <li><button id="button1" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/page2">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text3" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text4" class="blue" /></li>
      <li><button id="button2" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/page2andpage3">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="text" id="text5" class="red" /></li>
      <li><input type="text" id="text6" class="blue" /></li>
      <li><button id="button3" class="blue">Enter</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery is very useful if you want to run this logic in IE :)

Comment: You can just call `.form` instead of `.closest("form")`. An element can only belong to one form.

Comment: I haven seen any compatibility charts but I believe its ancient as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the closest form? I believe you just need this:

```js
$(element).closest('form').attr('action');
```

Documentation and additional examples [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: This only locates the closest form and then returns its `action` attribute value. It doesn't check to see if the attribute value is a partial match to the supplied input.

Comment: You're right. I was preparing an update, but someone else already answered properly.